# supportActionBar is null using Kotlin Android always

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Just now google has made the Kotlin as an official programming language, so started converting my files to Kotlin.

While converting my code, I am always getting null pointer exception when I try to use supportActionBar

```
    // set up action bar
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)
    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)

    // set the hamburger menu
    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar!!.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
```

My AndroidManifest entry is

```
      <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar />
```

No actionbar is having windowActionBar as false.
Every time I run the app, i get the null pointer exception whiel accessing the supportActionBar. Can anyone help me about it?

Comment: please upload your findViewById code for mToolbar

Comment: Did you forget to `setContentView`? It's hard to tell when you don't post the whole onCreate.

Comment: Maybe you are wrong. @EugenPechanec. Go to this link -https://medium.com/@juanchosaravia/learn-kotlin-while-developing-an-android-app-part-1-e0f51fc1a8b3   In MainActivity.kt file clearly it is mentioned.

Comment: Post your error

Comment: Added the kotlin extension and directly using the toolbar. It is working now... Thanks people

Comment: @CodeBoyChd ... could u help me plz . My setSupportActionBar is not recognizing

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha Check the theme of the app

Answer (score 5):

You can try

```
supportActionBar?.hide()
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Have you initialised mToolbar with its view id? If not then make it like this and check.

```
var mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar?
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)
```

Comment: Added the kotlin extension and directly using the toolbar. It is working now... Thanks people

Comment: @Maddy..Could u help me..My setSupportActionBar is not recognizing ?.What should i do now>

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha, extend your current activity by AppCompatActivity and set style of your activity as "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Comment: Thanks for ur comment..I am using the library which is extending the `FragmentActivity`  ..

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha, change it to AppCompatActivity if you can